# How does Haskell deal with documentation?

Tags: documentation, haskell

How do I get online documentation in Haskell?

Are there anything as elegant/handy as what Python does below?

```
>>> help([].count)
Help on built-in function count:

count(...)
    L.count(value) -> integer -- return number of occurrences of value
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to view the Haddock documentation within ghci, but there is [a ticket for it](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2168).

You can however get a small bit of info using the `:info` command, e.g.

```
ghci> :i nub
nub :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]     -- Defined in Data.List
```

so that you at least know where to look for the documentation for a particular function.

Answer (score 21):

### Interactive help in GHCi

The standard Haskell REPL is GHCi. While it is not possible to access complete documentation from within GHCi, it is possible to get quite a lot of useful info.

**Print types.** In 90% of cases this is enough to understand what a function does and how to use it.

```
ghci> :t zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

`:t` is short for `:type`.

**Print information about symbols.** This is useful to find what module does a symbol belong. For a data type it allows to see its definition and class instances. For a type class it allows to see its interface and a list of types which are its instances.

```
ghci> :i Bool 
data Bool = False | True    -- Defined in GHC.Bool
instance Bounded Bool -- Defined in GHC.Enum
instance Enum Bool -- Defined in GHC.Enum
instance Eq Bool -- Defined in GHC.Base
instance Ord Bool -- Defined in GHC.Base
instance Read Bool -- Defined in GHC.Read
instance Show Bool -- Defined in GHC.Show

ghci> :i Eq
class Eq a where
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    -- Defined in GHC.Classes
instance (Eq a) => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in Data.Maybe
instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Either a b) -- Defined in Data.Either
(many more instances follow)

ghci> :i zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
    -- Defined in GHC.List
```

`:i` is short for `:info`.

**Print kinds.** Use `:k` on type constructors.

```
ghci> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
ghci> :k Int
Int :: *
```

`:k` is short for `:kind`.

**Browse module's contents.** This allows to see what symbols an imported module offers.

```
ghci> :browse Data.List
(\\) :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
delete :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
deleteBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
...
(many lines follow)
```

`:t`, `:k` and `:i` work only for symbols in scope (you need to import module with `:m + Module.Name` first). `:browse` works for all available modules.

### Online documentation

Most Haskell libraries are documented with [Haddock](http://www.haskell.org/haddock/). You can open an HTML version of the documentation and read the details.

You can install it locally, if you use `--enable-documentation` flag in `cabal install`.

Otherwise, a good point to browse through all the documentation is [a package list on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html). It allows to see the documentation also for earlier versions of any package. Sometimes it is very useful.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle) to search for documentation by function name or its type signature (perhaps, approximate type signature). There's also a command-line offline version of this tool which you can get from hackage.